# stack level too deep when running rspec for controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

When I run rspec on my models, everything works fine. My controllers gets "stack level too deep" error.

```
$> rspec spec/models     
[DEPRECATED] The 'safe' write concern option has been deprecated in favor of 'w'.
............................................................

Finished in 1.28 seconds
60 examples, 0 failures
```

But for my controllers, i get this error "stack level too deep" when i add even just 1 example.

```
$> rspec spec/controllers 
F

Failures:

  1) GuestsController GET 'index' should render 200 page
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     SystemStackError:
       stack level too deep
     # /Users/iyanski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@littleknot/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:102

Finished in 0.02816 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/guests_controller_spec.rb:5 # GuestsController GET 'index' should render 200 page
```

guests_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe GuestsController do
  describe "GET 'index'" do
    it "should render 200 page" do

    end
  end
end
```

Below is my spec_helper.rb

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'factory_girl'

include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  config.order = "random"

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```

What do you think could have caused this?

Comment: A stack level too deep indicates, that you are in a loop that would never end. So Ruby decides to break this loop, and gives you this error. Your controller code would be helpful, and also your routes. Maybe you are in a redirect loop, or you are calling the same function recursively with no proper break or return statements

Comment: Did you you something special in your GuestsController?

Comment: What other stuff you are doing in Controller ? Is there GeoCoder you are using ? if yes then You need to mock the API request.

Comment: One-liner.. this is the only code.
class GuestsController < ApplicationController; def index; end; end

I'm still to write test for the first controller.

For the routes. there's only:

resources :guests